# Avoid "Parameterless Queries Error" with Linq Let clause

Tags: linq

I'd like my Linq query to create an additional column in the results on the fly.  In this case the column is a Class object I created that will contain image info.  I was wondering what the right way is of doing this:

```
var validPics = (from x in db.picsVotesTagsJs let picObj = new CarShowImages(x.picname) where x.enabled == 1 select x).Take(25);
var myArray = validPicSummaries.ToArray();
```

Line 2 gerenates the error:

**Only parameterless constructors and initializers are supported in LINQ to Entities.**

This is my first time using the Let clause.  My queries are usually pretty simple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create parameterless constructor and use some public property (e.g. `PicName`) to set picture name to your `CarShowImages` object:

```
var validPics = (from x in db.picsVotesTagsJs
                 where x.enabled == 1
                 select new CarShowImages { PicName = x.picname }).Take(25);
var myArray = validPics.ToArray();
```

Comment: I'll give it a try, I'm new at classes but I'm sure it will work.  Thanks.

Comment: But what about all the other columns?  I was not planning on putting them in my CarShowImages object.  Can't I just add the object to the linq result?

Comment: @Dave yes, you can create new anonymous object and return it: `select new { Image = new CarShowImages { PicName = x.picname }, Tags = x, OtherProperty = x.other }`